# Android Debugger shows inconsistent values, hits "impossible" breakpoint

Tags: android, gson, dalvik

I'm experiencing very strange behavior with the android debugger. A line of code in the GSON jar is being hit sporadically that should not be hit, causing an IllegalStateException to be thrown. To track down why the exception is thrown, I set a breakpoint on it's line. However, while poking around with the execution paused, I found the delegate somehow changed from null to set.

Specifically, once the breakpoint is hit, I would click another stack frame, then click back to the frame with the breakpoint, and suddenly the value of delegate is set. I then forced the execution out of the if-statement, and my code continued to run normally - no NPE or other issues.

I use proguard in my project, and can reproduce this on both the android L emulator and a handset.  Could this be a proguard bug, a debugger bug, or a gson bug?

See screenshots for the state of the debugger when the breakpoint is first hit, and then moments later after i've clicked around in it.

[image: State when breakpoint hit]
[image: State after i click to another stack frame and then return]

This is in Gson.java, line 885

Comment: Are both device and emulator running 5.0 (Lollipop)?  I'm curious if you see the same behavior in Dalvik, or only with Art.

Comment: It also repros on a 4.3 (API 18) emulator, right down to clicking up the callstack to get the delegate to appear. So much for that theory.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I think it might be a threading issue. I did a thread dump and Retrofit is simultaneously  doing Gson.fromJson on 3 threads....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a threading issue in Gson. The app i'm working on uses retrofit, which has a class GsonConverter that reuses the same Gson instance across multiple threads. I looked at a thread dump and saw at least three threads using the same gson instance simultaneously.

I tweaked GsonConverter to create a new Gson instance every time, and that seems to have solved my issue.

This was a total pain to solve because Gson would throw a JsonSyntaxException, which is completely unintuitive. I'll probably file a bug.